# Hibernate AutoIncrement non primary key based on foreign key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm working with a table that has an integer column and a foreign key. This integer has to be incremental, but it has to start again in 1 when the foreign key is changed.

Example:

```
Foreign 1, int col : 1 , 2 , 3...

Foreign 2, int col: 1 ,2 , 3, 4, 5 ...

Foreign 3, int col: 1, 2
```

This is my mapping so far: (Of course this doesn't does the trick)

```
public class Documento implements ModelEntity{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 11233L;

/*PK*/
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

/*FK*/
@Man yToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
@Cascade({})
private Type type;

/* This is the value that has to be AUTO-INCREMENT BASED ON FOREIGN_ID */
@Basic
private Integer idx;


}
```

Is there a way to do this with Hibernate (Oracle DB) ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this in hibernate, give us the create-statement for the table first please.

Comment: CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT
(
  ID           INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
  TYPE         INTEGER                         NOT NULL,   
  IDX       INTEGER,
  DOC          VARCHAR(255) 
);


 CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_TYPE
(
  ID           INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
  NAME         VARCHAR(255)                        
)

Comment: Great. Do you use Oracle 12c or newer?

Comment: I'm currently using Oracle 12 :)