# Increment field based on foreign key (JPA, Hibernate, Oracle DB)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to have a field auto-increment based on a foreign key? I would like to achieve this with JPA (Hibernate) and Oracle DB. I've read it's not possible with `MySQL`'s `InnoDB` engine.

It is pretty much like the following questions:

- [mysql-second-auto-increment-field-based-on-foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786665/mysql-second-auto-increment-field-based-on-foreign-key)
- [mysql-auto-increment-based-on-foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605085/mysql-auto-increment-based-on-foreign-key)

But these are only based on MySQL tables itself. Not JPA & Oracle DB.

- [hibernate-autoincrement-non-primary-key-based-on-foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146112/hibernate-autoincrement-non-primary-key-based-on-foreign-key)

Is exactly as I need, but sadly there is no answer.

As a concrete example, consider a simple example. Each `Student` has multiple `Book`s. The `Book` has a primary key (regular increment), but it also has a `followUpNumber`. This number starts at 1 and auto-increments for each added `Book` to a `Student`. Meaning every `Student` has a list of `Book` of which the `followUpNumber` starts at 1 everytime. Here's the `Book` table to display what i mean:

```
|------|------------|-----------------|
|  id  | student_id | followup_number |
|------|------------|-----------------|
|  1   |      1     |        1        |
|  2   |      1     |        2        |
|  3   |      1     |        3        |
|  4   |      2     |        1        |
|  5   |      1     |        4        |
|  6   |      1     |        5        |
|  7   |      2     |        2        |
|  8   |      3     |        1        |
|  9   |      3     |        2        |
|------|------------|-----------------|
```

- **id** being the primary key
- **student_id** being the foreign key to student
- **followup_number** being the field which starts at 1 for every *student_id*

Is there something like a custom [`@GeneratedValue`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) strategy that doesn't need to be placed on primary key fields? My current solution is just before adding a new `Book`, iterate over all `Book`s, get the highest followup_number and assign that number + 1 to the new book. But I feel there must be a cleaner, more elegant way to do this.

Comment: A database trigger on insert comes to mind, it doesn't need to be solved by JPA. But I'd be curious to see JPA-oriented solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [@OrderColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation can be used.

> public @interface OrderColumn
>
> Specifies a column that is used to
>   maintain the persistent order of a list. The persistence provider is
>   responsible for maintaining the order upon retrieval and in the
>   database. The persistence provider is responsible for updating the
>   ordering upon flushing to the database to reflect any insertion,
>   deletion, or reordering affecting the list.
>
> The OrderColumn annotation is specified on a OneToMany or ManyToMany
>   relationship or on an element collection. The OrderColumn annotation
>   is specified on the side of the relationship that references the
>   collection that is to be ordered. The order column is not visible as
>   part of the state of the entity or embeddable class.
>
> The OrderBy annotation should be used for ordering that is visible as
>   persistent state and maintained by the application. The OrderBy
>   annotation is not used when OrderColumn is specified.
>
> The order column must be of integral type. The persistence provider
>   maintains a contiguous (non-sparse) ordering of the values of the
>   order column when updating the association or element collection. The
>   order column value for the first element is 0.

The only drawback is that the number for the first element is 0, not 1

---

An example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
@SequenceGenerator(name="student_seq", initialValue=1, 
                   allocationSize=10,sequenceName="STUDDENT_SEQ")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="student_seq")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="student")
    @OrderColumn(name="FOLLOWUP_NUMBER")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    ...............
    ...............
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="book_seq", initialValue=1, 
                   allocationSize=10, sequenceName="BOOK_SEQ")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="book_seq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
    private Student student;

    @Column(name="TITLE", nullable=false)
    private String title;

    ..................
    ..................
}
```

---

And this simple test case:

```
EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();

tr.begin();

for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    Student student = new Student("Student name " + j);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        student.getBooks().add(new Book("Some book" + i, student));
    }
    em.persist(student);
}

tr.commit();
```

generates the following tables (tested on Oracle 12c and Hibernate 5.2):

```
select * from student;
   ID NAME               
----- --------------------
    1 Student name 1      
    2 Student name 2      
    3 Student name 3      
    4 Student name 4
    .......
    .......
```

---

```
select * from book
order by student_id, followup_number;
   ID TITLE                STUDENT_ID FOLLOWUP_NUMBER
----- -------------------- ---------- ---------------
    1 Some book1                    1          0
    2 Some book2                    1          1
    3 Some book3                    1          2
    4 Some book4                    1          3
    5 Some book5                    1          4
    6 Some book6                    1          5
    7 Some book7                    1          6
    8 Some book8                    1          7
    9 Some book9                    1          8
   10 Some book10                   1          9
   11 Some book1                    2          0
   12 Some book2                    2          1
   13 Some book3                    2          2
   14 Some book4                    2          3
   15 Some book5                    2          4
   16 Some book6                    2          5
   17 Some book7                    2          6
   18 Some book8                    2          7
   19 Some book9                    2          8
   20 Some book10                   2          9
   21 Some book1                    3          0
   22 Some book2                    3          1
   23 Some book3                    3          2
   ........
   ........
```

---

A performance might be another disadvantage, because for each book Hibernate generates two SQL commands - one insert, and then one update of `FOLLOWUP_NUMBER` column.
 What is worse, when some book is removed, then Hibernate generates all numbers for a given student again and fires updates of `FOLLOWUP_NUMBER` column for all remaining books.

---

**EDIT**

---

> But what bothers me is "The order column is not visible as part of the
>   state of the entity or embeddable class.". The data is just as I'd
>   like it in the DB, but it isn't reflected onto my entity. While I'd
>   like to make use of this FOLLOWUP_NUMBER

I don't know if this is possibe in JPA, but the Hibernate extension `@Formula` can be used in this case:

```
class Book{
    .......
    .......

    @Formula(value="FOLLOWUP_NUMBER")
    private Long followUpNumber;

    public Long getFollowUpNumber() {
        return followUpNumber;
    }

    ........
    ........
}
```

This calculated field can be even queried, for example the below test case:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
   "Select b FROM Book b JOIN b.student s " +
   "WHERE s.name = :studentname AND b.followUpNumber = :follownbr"
);
query.setParameter("studentname", "Student name 6");
query.setParameter("follownbr", Long.valueOf(4));
Book book = (Book)query.getSingleResult();

System.out.println("Found book = " + book.getTitle());
System.out.println("book follow nbr= " + book.getFollowUpNumber());
```

gives the following result:

```
Found book = Some book5
book follow nbr= 4
```

and Hibernate uses the below SQL to find that book:

```
    select
        book0_.id as id1_0_,
        book0_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT_ID3_0_,
        book0_.TITLE as TITLE2_0_,
        book0_.FOLLOWUP_NUMBER as formula0_ 
    from
        Book book0_ 
    inner join
        STUDENT student1_ 
            on book0_.STUDENT_ID=student1_.Id 
    where
        student1_.NAME=? 
        and book0_.FOLLOWUP_NUMBER=?
```

Comment: Good to see there's a possible solution with JPA. But what bothers me is *"The order column is not visible as part of the state of the entity or embeddable class."*. The data is just as I'd like it in the DB, but it isn't reflected onto my entity. While I'd like to make use of this `FOLLOWUP_NUMBER`.

Comment: `@Formula` extension can be used in this case, I've appended an example to the answer.